# Black formatter doesn't break long line

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, wsl-2, python-black

I have a python project with Flake8 and Black installed. I'm using VSCode, with the following workspace configuration in `settings.json`: `"black-formatter.args": ["--line-length=80"],`. I also tried: `"black-formatter.args": ["--line-length, "80"],`

This arg is also manually addedin the settings UI for the user, WSL, and workspace.

I also tried running black in the terminal with the arg like this: `black --line-length=80 conftest.py`

The output:

```
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file left unchanged.
```

When I manually break the long line, black actually undoes the change. I can't just configure the project to ignore this error, because this is a shared project and this style has to be enforced.

I'm using WSL2 inside Windows 11, python version 3.11.5. I'm also using poetry version 1.7.1. Any help is appreciated.

I also posted this on the Black repo [here](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/4177)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please post the offending line where black does this, if it's a bug - report to maintainer. As a workaround, break manually and wrap with `# fmt: off` and `# fnt: on`.

Comment: I don't think I can post the lines since it's for work, but it happens on multiple lines. I'll post it . I forgot to mention the project uses poetry, could this cause an issue? I'll add it to the question.